# How to handle two custom cells in one UITableView with UISegmentedControl Actions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, custom-cell

Hi i am new to iOS and SO also. i am facing a problem in my app to display the two custom cells in one tableview with selection of segmented control.when the user click on the segmented=0,it displays the one custom cell and segmented=1 display the second custom cell.
Here is my code upto now i tried,

```
 -(void)callSegmentSelected
{
value1 = (int)segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:"url"];
        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:catid];
        NSData *myJSONData =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myJSONData]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(str.length > 0)
        {
            NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *error;
            array =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

            [myTableView reloadData];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
}
else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
{
}
```

Here is my tableview Delegate methods

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return array.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value1 == 0)
{
static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
Cell1 * cell = (Cell1 *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
        NSArray *myNib;
        myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Cell1" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [myNib lastObject];
}
    cell.examLbl.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"examtitle"];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    [myTableView reloadData];

    return cell;
}
else
{
    if (value1 == 1)
    {
        static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
        Cell2 *cell = (ContestRewardCell *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *myNib;
            myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"cell2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell =[myNib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.titleLbl.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
        myTableView.dataSource = self;
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        [myTableView reloadData];
        return cell;
    }
}
return nil;
}
```

In this code there are no errors,i checked with debugging mode data will coming to "cell.examLbl.text",but not displaying the custom cell in tableview.What i did mistake in this Code Please help me any one.
Thanks in advance.

Here is answer for my problem, i am not implemented the this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value1 == 0)
{
    return 102;
}
else if(value1 == 1)
{
    return 193;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug it & see if you go inside if (value1 == 0) &if (value1 == 1)

Comment: Checked but not working.it displays like this 2016-02-12 18:51:17.725 Tugain[15084:222927] Examid: 1
(lldb) po value1
1

Comment: myTableView.dataSource = self;
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        [myTableView reloadData]; these codes should be in viewdidload, not inside cellForRow method.

Comment: Ok. i removed that but not working @RJVKumar

Answer (score 0):

you need to first register the cell nib in viewDid load

`[YourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@“YourCellNibName” bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@“Identifier”];`

then use the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[TableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@“MyTableViewCell” bundle:nil]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[myTableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell”];

 cell.labelTitle=@"cell”;

 return cell;


}
```

Comment: How? can give a example r link!